# Maven: Dependency convergence error for com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0

Tags: android, maven

We get this error when trying to include following dependency in our project:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-fragment</artifactId>
      <version>28.0.0</version>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
```

we have pasted complete trace [here](https://gist.github.com/siddjain/549a6c721c6399b185da2376f6817933). as far as we can see it is saying that the same assembly depends on two different versions. how can that be possible?

```
and
+-com.google.zxing:android:4.7.10
  +-com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0
    +-com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0
      +-com.android.support:collections:28.0.0
        +-com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
and
+-com.google.zxing:android:4.7.10
  +-com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0
    +-com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0
      +-android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1
        +-android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1
          +-com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
```

How can we fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this code at the bottom of your Gradle file where there is the list of dependencies

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support' && !requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
            details.useVersion '28.0.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always override the old version of the library by adding the library to your dependencies. For your problem, try overriding by adding the `support-annotations` dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>28.0.0</version>
      <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: yes that is what we have in our pom. the aar is not needed per https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/support-annotations/28.0.0 but we still get the convergence error hence the question